# MATLAB MEX : -std=C++11 used but still mex error

Tags: c++, matlab, c++11, mex

I am using Windows 10 and trying to generate gasonMex.mexw64 file for MatlabAPI of COCO dataset.

The command I am using is `mex -v COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS -std=c++11 -Wall" -largeArrayDims gasonMex.cpp`

I also tried using `mex -v CXXFLAGS='$CXXFLAGS -std=c++11 -Wall' -largeArrayDims gasonMex.cpp` but got the same error.

---

```
Verbose mode is on.

... Looking for compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'MW_MINGW64_LOC' ...Yes ('C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset').
... Looking for file 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset' ...Yes.
Found installed compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
Set PATH = C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin; C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\include\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\include; C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\simulink\include;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\lib\win64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\; C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL; C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\IntelSGXPSW\bin\x64\Release\;C:\Program Files\Intel\IntelSGXPSW\bin\win32\Release\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\OpenNI\Bin64;D:\Bin64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\;C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin;
Set INCLUDE = C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\\INCLUDE\gl;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\include;;
Set LIB = C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\lib;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Lib\amd64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\\Lib\X64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\AMD64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\lib\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64;
Set MW_TARGET_ARCH = win64;win64;
Set LIBPATH = C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Lib\amd64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\\LIB\X64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\AMD64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64;
```

### Options file details

```
Compiler location: C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset
Options file: C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2016b\mex_C++_win64.xml
CMDLINE2 : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++ -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -s -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def" C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\cpp_mexapi_version.obj   -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas -o gasonMex.mexw64
CXX : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++
COMPILER : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++
DEFINES : -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
MATLABMEX : -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
CXXFLAGS : -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11
INCLUDE : -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include"
CXXOPTIMFLAGS : -O -DNDEBUG
CXXDEBUGFLAGS : -g
LDXX : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++
LINKER : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++
LDFLAGS : -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined
LDTYPE : -shared
LINKEXPORT : -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/mexFunction.def"
LINKEXPORTVER : -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def"
LIBLOC : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64
LINKLIBS : -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas
LDOPTIMFLAGS : -s
LDDEBUGFLAGS : -g
OBJEXT : .obj
LDEXT : .mexw64
SETENV : set COMPILER=g++ 
            set COMPFLAGS=-c -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  
            set OPTIMFLAGS=-O -DNDEBUG 
            set DEBUGFLAGS=-g 
            set LINKER=g++ 
            set LINKFLAGS=-m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/mexFunction.def" 
            set LINKDEBUGFLAGS=-g
            set NAME_OUTPUT= -o "%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%"
MINGWROOT : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset
MATLABROOT : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b
ARCH : win64
SRC : "D:\MS Informatics\5th Semester\cocostuff-master\downloads\cocoApi\cocoapi-336d2a27c91e3c0663d2dcf0b13574674d30f88e\MatlabAPI\private\gasonMex.cpp";"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp"
OBJ : C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj;C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
OBJS : C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\cpp_mexapi_version.obj 
SRCROOT : D:\MS Informatics\5th Semester\cocostuff-master\downloads\cocoApi\cocoapi-336d2a27c91e3c0663d2dcf0b13574674d30f88e\MatlabAPI\private\gasonMex
DEF : C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.def
EXP : gasonMex.exp
LIB : gasonMex.lib
EXE : gasonMex.mexw64
ILK : gasonMex.ilk
MANIFEST : gasonMex.mexw64.manifest
TEMPNAME : gasonMex
EXEDIR : 
EXENAME : gasonMex
COMPFLAGS :  -std=c++11 -Wall
OPTIM : -O -DNDEBUG
LINKOPTIM : -s
CMDLINE1_0 : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++ -c -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O -DNDEBUG "D:\MS Informatics\5th Semester\cocostuff-master\downloads\cocoApi\cocoapi-336d2a27c91e3c0663d2dcf0b13574674d30f88e\MatlabAPI\private\gasonMex.cpp" -o C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj
CMDLINE1_1 : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++ -c -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O -DNDEBUG "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp" -o C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
```

---

The error message I get is

---

```
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++ -c -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O -DNDEBUG "D:\MS Informatics\5th Semester\cocostuff-master\downloads\cocoApi\cocoapi-336d2a27c91e3c0663d2dcf0b13574674d30f88e\MatlabAPI\private\gasonMex.cpp" -o C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj
C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++ -c -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O -DNDEBUG "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp" -o C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++ -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -s -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def" C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\cpp_mexapi_version.obj   -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas -o gasonMex.mexw64
Error using mex
C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj:gasonMex.cpp:(.text+0x1348): undefined reference to `jsonParse(char*, char**, JsonValue*, JsonAllocator&)'
C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj:gasonMex.cpp:(.text+0x1353): undefined reference to `jsonStrError(int)'
C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj:gasonMex.cpp:(.text+0x17af): undefined reference to `jsonParse(char*, char**, JsonValue*, JsonAllocator&)'
C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj:gasonMex.cpp:(.text+0x17ba): undefined reference to `jsonStrError(int)'
C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj:gasonMex.cpp:(.text+0x202c): undefined reference to `jsonParse(char*, char**, JsonValue*, JsonAllocator&)'
C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj:gasonMex.cpp:(.text+0x2037): undefined reference to `jsonStrError(int)'
C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj:gasonMex.cpp:(.text+0x2363): undefined reference to `JsonAllocator::deallocate()'
C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_71745656324277_9188\gasonMex.obj:gasonMex.cpp:(.text+0x240a): undefined reference to `JsonAllocator::deallocate()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

My doubt is similar to [MATLAB Mex : Already had -std=c++11, but still got error of "compiler and library support"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690484/matlab-mex-already-had-std-c11-but-still-got-error-of-compiler-and-librar) but I didn't have enough reputation points to comment there.

Does somebody know what I am doing wrong? Or faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that the linker couldn't find symbols. When it says `error: ld returned 1 exit status` then the linker (`ld`) produced an error, not the compiler (`g++`).

Since all the functions that the linker cannot find have "json" in their name, I would assume that you are missing a JSON library.

If you know what library is expected you link to, you can do:

```
mex <...> gasonMex.cpp -ljson
```

(assuming that `json` is the name of the library (evaluates to `libjson.a` or `libjson.so`). There is also an `-L` argument to specify the directory where to look for the library. Alternatively, simply pass the library name with full path to the `mex` command:

```
mex <...> gasonMex.cpp dir/to/libjson.a
```